# Serialize data from ManyToMany queryset

Tags: django

```
class Food(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=199)
    tags = TaggableManager()

class Box(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    food = models.ManyToManyField(Food, blank=True, null=True)
```

**python manage.py shell:**

```
box = Box.objects.filter(id=1)
myfood = box.food.all()
```

I need JSON with all `myfood`. How can I serialize this data?

My try:

`data = serializers.serialize("json", myfood)`

but I have this error:

```
    if field.rel.through._meta.auto_created:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

**Full example: (python manage.py shell):**

```
>>> from django.core import serializers
>>> from app.models import *
>>> box = Box.objects.filter(id=1)
>>> myfood = box.food.all()
>>> data = serializers.serialize("json", myfood)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/Pulpit/x/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 99, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/home/user/Pulpit/x/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 58, in serialize
    self.handle_m2m_field(obj, field)
  File "/home/user/Pulpit/x/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 65, in handle_m2m_field
    if field.rel.through._meta.auto_created:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. When and how do you see that error? Inside a shell? When trying to print data? In the runserver?

Comment: @yuvi Inside the shell

Comment: It's weird what you're getting from `print myfood` because box is a QuerySet objects (and not a box object). you should probably be doing `box = Box.objects.get(id=1)`, right?

Comment: Also, I just recreated the entire thing and had exactly zero problems serializing the data like you did there.

Comment: @yuvi Thanks. My model example was not complete here. I have also `TaggableManager()`. Here is the same problem: https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-autofixture/issues/20#issuecomment-27507902 How can I fix it?

Comment: 1) please share the entirety of your models 2) what version of django-taggit are you using?

Comment: I use latest version (pip install django-taggit) Please look at updated code

Comment: Before I start messing with this, I'd love it if try downgrading your taggit to version 10 as the release of version 11 mentions it has ["Made the tagging relations unserializeable again"](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the serializer that django comes with, specifically this function which handles m2m fields:

```
def handle_m2m_field(self, obj, field):
    if field.rel.through._meta.auto_created:
        if self.use_natural_keys and hasattr(field.rel.to, 'natural_key'):
            m2m_value = lambda value: value.natural_key()
        else:
            m2m_value = lambda value: smart_text(value._get_pk_val(), strings_only=True)
        self._current[field.name] = [m2m_value(related)
                           for related in getattr(obj, field.name).iterator()]
```

The problem is, when it iterates over the fields for your object, it also finds the TaggableManager (which is a manager), and treats it like a field. Then, the line `field.rel.through._meta.auto_created` causes an error (because it isn't a field). There are two possible fixes I can think of:

1. Build your own serializer
2. Apply [this fix.](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/pull/159/files) Open up your django-taggit managers.py and change this line (inside the TaggableManager init function):

   ```
   class TaggableManager(RelatedField, Field):
        def __init__(self, verbose_name=_("Tags"),
            help_text=_("A comma-separated list of tags."), through=None, blank=False):
            Field.__init__(self, verbose_name=verbose_name, help_text=help_text, blank=blank)
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   class TaggableManager(RelatedField, Field):
        def __init__(self, verbose_name=_("Tags"),
            help_text=_("A comma-separated list of tags."), through=None, blank=False):
            Field.__init__(self, verbose_name=verbose_name, help_text=help_text, blank=blank, null=True, serialize=False)
   ```

It's kind of a hack but maybe it will be good enough for you. Sorry I can't be of any more help!

Comment: @marcelosalloum this answer was posted a year ago. A lot has changed since then. I suggest you open up a new question, provide your code and relevant details, and also give a link to this answer and mention that this solution didn't work. Maybe the fix is too old, maybe django-taggit already resolved the old issue and you're facing something new, maybe you did a simple syntax error. I have no way of blindly telling you why it doesn't work for you.